# How to write simple game/app for 3D screens (Evo3d, LG 3d)

Tags: graphics, 3d, stereo-3d

Can anyone give me a hint or example how to write in real 3d on canvas?
I do not mean 3d projected on 2d like OpenGL or vectors, but on a screen as LG 3d or EVO3d. What if I have 2 stereoscopic images and want to show them as one. How can I do this?

---

(I prefer not to use OpenGL to render the real 3d since my graphics are so simple it does not require the use of OpenGL, think of it as a standard gallery that wants to display a picture/bitmap or pre-rendered animation)

- I did some research before posting this question (of course) and found that many 3d-foto's are nothing but 2 fotos next to each other, does that maybe work for a game too? That I have to write on a canvas of dimensions (2*width, height) in stead of (width, height)?